# No external output with hdmi usb switch but yes on Windows

Tags: power-management, xrandr, external-monitor, thunderbolt

I've a laptop that has two thunderbolt ports. I wanted to see the video into an external monitor, so I have bought a usb-c to hdmi switch. On Windows everything works correctly, but here on Ubuntu (I'm using KDE) it does not. If I go in Displays, I just see my laptop, and sometimes it blinks and I can see the other monitor display (without seeing anything however in the external monitor).

It looks also like the usb switch, that is plugged both to my laptop and to the power, that on Linux, is not able to transmit power to th e laptop.. or better, after some seconds it plugs off.. then back on, and so on..

Any hints?

Thanks

[edit] the switch has both a HDMI port and a VGA. If I plug the VGA as well I can see both external monitors, but at a lower speed. In the specs there is written that the resolution would be 1080p in both monitors at most. It seems like if Linux is not able to manage the power through this switch if the resolution is higher than 1080p